# String evaluation in powershell

Tags: powershell

I was expecting $Flag_CreditTrend  to be 1. But it equals 0. 
Any ideas?

```
$Note = "test, up"
$CreditScoreTrend  = ($Note -split ',')[1].trim()
$Flag_CreditTrend = 0
$CreditScoreTrend 
if ($CredScoretrend -match 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
#if ($CredScoretrend -like 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
#if ($CredScoretrend -eq 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
$Flag_CreditTrend
```

Comment: There's a typo in the `if` statement condition: `$CredScoreTrend` -> `$CreditScoreTrend`

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I could not figure out for the life of me, why something as basic as this would not work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what you wrote:

```
$Note = "test, up"
$CreditScoreTrend  = ($Note -split ',')[1].trim()
$Flag_CreditTrend = 0
$CreditScoreTrend 
if ($CredScoretrend -match 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
#if ($CredScoretrend -like 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
#if ($CredScoretrend -eq 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
$Flag_CreditTrend
```

The 5th line `if ($CredScoretrend -match 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}` is using the variable `$CredScoretrend` instead of your intended variable `$CreditScoreTrend`. Since this new variable is unassigned, it does not match 'up' as you expected. This returns false, so `Flag_CreditTrend` is never assigned to be 1. As a result, `$Flag_CreditTrend` is returning the value of 0 that you assigned it on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Variable Reference Mistake,Please look at the Commented Line

```
$Note = "test, up"
$CreditScoreTrend  = ($Note -split ',')[1].trim()
$Flag_CreditTrend = 0
$CreditScoreTrend 
if ($CreditScoreTrend -match 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}#here CreditScoreTrend is to be used
#if ($CredScoretrend -like 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
#if ($CredScoretrend -eq 'up') {$Flag_CreditTrend = 1}
$Flag_CreditTrend
```